# Missing ecommerce data and bad event tracking code

Tags: android, google-analytics, admob, event-tracking

I have been using Google Admob and Google Analytics to track my apps so far with no any issue. I currently had notification on Analytics page as below:

> Missing Ecommerce Data
>   Property Default view is configured for Ecommerce, but no data is flowing.
>   Bad Event Tracking Code
>   (not set) entry present in reports for property xxx | Android.

**Note:** Seems, app tracking also stopped for last 2 days. I have not made any changes in neither Analytics configurations nor within Android app.

How can i solve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: I am seeing the same "Bad Event Tracking Code" warning in my analytics account. From what i can say logging happens as normal though. Would be curios to know what is going on as well.

Comment: I recently heard that accounts related with Admob and Analytics will be effecting from some changes Google doing. But i have not much idea what exactly it is. maybe we need to make some updates in our coding side as well.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem for us, suddenly stopped tracking eCommerce data for no reason, we haven't made any code changes so i'm not sure why. I heard that Google may be phasing out classic GA since UA is out of beta but i thought they would inform us rather than making changes and telling nobody.

Comment: Not likely, since legacy (urchin era) tracking code is still supported. Also they indicate there is still about year and a half till phasing out of Classic GA. c.f. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/?hl=en#phase-4